# Can I create a customised literal class in rst?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm writing some coding tutorials in rST/Sphinx and I'd like to differentiate the input (ie: the code-block) from the output (to the terminal).  Because the output needs to be literal too, I can't simply use a custom class or container, as these still get interpreted and don't display correctly (see below).  How can I create a class or container or something which I can apply to a subset of literal blocks?

Note that this doesn't need to be anything fancy - maybe just changing the background colour on my "output" blocks compared to my "code-block" blocks.

I've tried:

Creating a custom class called "terminal", but this is still interpreted and returns errors about its contents:

```
.. container:: terminal

    -----------------------------------------------
                  MY **EXAMPLE** GOES HERE   
    -----------------------------------------------
```

... produces an interpreted output, the class is applied correctly, but the horizontal lines are missing, the "EXAMPLE" is bold etc.

Nesting a literal block inside the terminal container:

```
::

    .. container:: terminal

        -----------------------------------------------
                    MY **EXAMPLE** GOES HERE   
        -----------------------------------------------
```

... produces the literal output formatted as input code:

```
.. container:: terminal

    -----------------------------------------------
                MY **EXAMPLE** GOES HERE
    -----------------------------------------------
```

Nesting the other way around:

```
.. container:: terminal

    ::

    -----------------------------------------------
            MY **EXAMPLE** GOES HERE
    -----------------------------------------------
```

... produces a div with the `terminal` formatting around a nested div with the literal block, which retains the standard literal formatting (which I want to over-ride).

I think there must be something really simple I'm missing but I really can't see it!

Answer (score 0):

Try [`.. code-block:: bash`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-code-block) where "bash" is the name of the language to which you want syntax highlighting applied. [Available syntaxes](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/#lexers-for-various-shells) are provided by Pygments as "lexers".

```
.. code-block:: bash

    -----------------------------------------------
                  MY **EXAMPLE** GOES HERE   
    -----------------------------------------------
```

If you are dissatisfied with the syntax highlighting provided by your Sphinx theme, you can override it with a [custom style](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-sphinx%5D+custom+style).

As an example of what is possible, I changed the style for a specific selector.  Put something similar in your theme's CSS.

```
div.highlight-text > table > tbody > tr > td.code > div > pre {
    background-color: #32cd32;
}
```

[image: Custom Sphinx Style]

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried this too using `text` as the name of the language. It gives the same result as just using the standard `::` (I don't want any syntax highlighting, I just want to change the background colour and remove all interpretation).

Comment: There is no interpretation of reST markup within `code-block`. `text` as the language is just plain text without highlighting. And as I further mentioned, you can apply a custom style with CSS as you see fit.

Comment: Hi again.  I have tried what (as far as I can follow) you've suggested, but it just doesn't work.  I know there's no interpretation of markup in the `code-block`, but neither is there the ability to have custom formatting (ie: a different background colour).  If I follow the second way (the link is great, but again, only applies to interpreted blocks) I can control the format, but the interpretation is still there.  If possible, please could you post code that you've found to work, as I'm just not getting it?

Comment: What did you try? Did you look at any of the examples to which I linked?

Comment: Yes, I had already tried them both. *NB* I don't want any syntax highlighting, just literal text. The trouble is that there are two issues:

1: Create literal text.
This is solved using the code-block or :: directives, but if you use them I cannot also style the text.  I end up with a styled box around unstyled literal text. 

2: Styling the text. 
This is solved using custom classes ... but I cannot avoid the interpretation of the markdown. I end up with styled, marked-down text.

Your solutions - and all mine so far too - worked on one or other issue, but not both :(

Comment: Answer edited to demonstrate CSS selectors and applying custom styles in a Sphinx theme.

Comment: Shell session output (i.e. text in the terminal) is _not_ a Bash script. The syntax for this should be `console`, `sh-session`, or `shell-session`.